# how to fix Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability In Android

Tags: android, flutter, zip, google-play-console, startapp

**I have an app that has startapp(0.5.1) ads, but after reviewing, I got the following error:**

Your app has an unsafe decompression pattern that could lead to a "scan path" vulnerability.
Please see this Google Help Center article for how to fix the issue.

```
 . com.startapp.networkTest.utils.j.a
 . com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.j.n.a
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I solved it with the latest version of SDK
implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.9.2'

From Javadoc https://javadoc.io/doc/com.startapp/inapp-sdk/latest/index.html
greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this version of `startapp`:

```
implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.9.1'
```